Typescript with Express.js throws error: "No Overload matches this call"
This is the SystemUserController.ts:
export const editSystemUser = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response | undefined> => {
        const { id } = req.params; // Güncellenecek kullanıcının ID'si
        const { first_name, middle_name, last_name, username, email, password, is_active } = req.body;
      
        try {
          // Kullanıcıyı bul
          const user = await SystemUser.findById(id);
          if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Kullanıcı bulunamadı' });
          }
      
          // Yeni şifre varsa, hashle
          if (password) {
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
          }
      
          // Kullanıcı bilgilerini güncelle
          user.first_name = first_name || user.first_name;
          user.middle_name = middle_name || user.middle_name;
          user.last_name = last_name || user.last_name;
          user.username = username || user.username;
          user.email = email || user.email;
          user.is_active = is_active !== undefined ? is_active : user.is_active;
      
          // Güncellenmiş kullanıcıyı kaydet
          await user.save();
      
          res.status(200).json({ message: 'Kullanıcı güncellendi', user });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).json({ message: 'Sunucu hatası' });
        }
};

And this is systemUserRoutes.ts:
import { Router } from "express";
import { editSystemUser, registerUser } from "../controllers/SystemUserController";

const userRouter = Router();

userRouter.post('/register', registerUser);
userRouter.post('/updateUser/:id', editSystemUser);

export default userRouter;

In systemUserRoutes.ts, when I write this line
userRouter.post('/updateUser/:id', editSystemUser);

editSystemUser throws an error:

No Overload matches this call

error

I think return res.status(404).json... is a mistake because you are not expected to return any value from a route handler. To end the execution at that point you can do res.status(404).json....; return;
